# Unicode to string in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.x

If I define the variable

```
x = 'Ááa Éée'
```

then the output of

```
print x
```

is

```
Ááa Éée
```

But I have an `unicode` object

```
x = u'Ááa Éée'
```

and I need *the same output* as before. To do this, I tried converting it to a `str` with

```
str(u'Ááa Éée')
```

but it didn't work.

How can I do this? (I'm only interested exit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str(u'Ááa Éée')` is not working, because this conversion unicode -> str uses encoding ASCII by default and characters ÁáÉé are not present in ASCII.

You need this: `u'Ááa Éée'.encode("UTF-8")` - if your terminal uses UTF-8.

Things about unicode can be complicated, it's better to read something about it:

- [Unicode HOWTO - Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) ([Python 3 version](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/unicode.html))
- [Explain it like I'm five: Python and Unicode?](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1g62eh/explain_it_like_im_five_python_and_unicode/)
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, `print u"Ááa Éée"` should give you the exact same output as `print "Ááa Éée"`. Maybe you are confusing with printing the representation of each one on the terminal. Anyway, if what you're asking is how to convert the unicode to str, use `x.encode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 0):

x = u'Ááa Éée' is unicode string

so, you You can only use `unicode()` instead `str()`

use unicode string

You need to specify the encoding

`string = x.encode('utf-8') #utf-16 or ...`

`print string.decode('utf-8')`